# sed linux дважды выводятся строки

Tags: linux, sed, терминал

Нужно заменить строки, в которых содержится подстрока на другую строку, и вывести получившийся список на экран. Делаю это следующим образом:

```
sed 's/.*подстрока.*/строка_на_которую_надо_заменить/p' путь_к_файлу
```

В результате получаю список, в котором `строка_на_которую_надо_заменить` повторяется дважды. То есть вместо того, чтобы просто заменить одну строку на другую, получается, что одна строка заменяется на две. Почему так происходит и как это исправить?

Comment: буква p в конце как раз заставляет печатать еще раз

Comment: @Mike спасибо, помогло